# Is there any point to using wp_unique_post_slug?

Tags: posts, slug, wp-insert-post

From what I can tell, [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) will automatically append a -# to your post slug. So why does [wp_unique_post_slug](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) exist?

Is it just there for legacy purposes or is there still a good reason to use it?

Comment: if you scroll down in in the source code of `wp_insert_post()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#source to line 3679, you will see that that function actually calls `wp_unique_post_slug()` ...

Comment: It exists because it's the one which automatically adds that `-#` (i.e. number suffix) to the post slug when there's an existing post with the same slug without the suffix. So the function exists and being called from `wp_insert_post()` to make sure the slug is *unique* - just as the function name implies.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters have noticed [`wp_unique_post_slug`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/) is called from `wp_insert_post` to ensure there are no double slugs. It is also called from two other functions, which explains why it is a separate function and not incorporated in `wp_insert_post`.

A little used feature is the possibility to apply filters present in `wp_unique_post_slug`. There are two of them:

1. `pre_wp_unique_post_slug` allows you to completely bypass the unique post slug generation, for instance if you want to use a completely different slug for your posts (say, based on some metafield in stead of the title).
2. `wp_unique_post_slug` allows you to change the unique post slug that has been generated, for instance if you dislike the number-suffix and want to replace it with something else or if you want to prepend every slug with the post tag or so.

So, apart from the obvious fact that `wp_unique_post_slug` is an essential WP function, there are also advanced uses.